# How can the IDs of visible jqGrid grids be determined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, visible

I have a page with severl jqGrids, but only one is visible at a time.  I want a simple function to return which one is visible at any time.  Is there some function like this, which would show which divs are visible:

```
$('div').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':visible')){
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    }
});
```

Is there something like this that can parse through all jqGrids on a page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need probably something like the following

```js
$("table.ui-jqgrid-btable:visible").attr('id');
```

If no grid are on the table you will get `undefined` value. If more as one grid is visible you will get the id of the first one.

To have array of ids of all visible grids you can use the following code

```js
var ids = $.map($("table.ui-jqgrid-btable:visible"), function(value) {
        return value.id;
    });
// now we have all ids in the array
alert(ids.join()); // display all as comma-separated
```

You can make the above code more safe with the test for `grid` expandos:

```
var ids = $.map($("table.ui-jqgrid-btable:visible"), function(value) {
        if (value.grid) { return value.id; }
    });
// now we have all ids in the array
alert(ids.join()); // display all as comma-separated
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have seen, All grids are wrapped with a div class `ui-jqgrid`. So try something like below,

```
$('div.ui-jqgrid:visible').each(function () {
   alert(this.id); //above would return the gview_<table_id> or gbox_<table_id> or 
                   //something_<table_id>
   alert($(this).find('.ui-jqgrid-btable').attr('id')); //should return table_id
});
```